# Howto boot into console with Ubuntu 12.04 USB Stick?

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb-drive

A Lenovo G575 laptop freezes during boot since I upgraded to 12.04. The same, when I boot it with a 12.04 live USB stick.

I guess that it freezes when the GUI is initialized. So I would like to boot into the console only without any X11.

But I didn't find corresponding boot options to do that. Can this be done from the USB boot menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I didn't find corresponding boot options to do that.

When you boot the laptop (no USB stick), keep shift pressed down as soon as the BIOS screen comes up. You'll then see the Grub menu, with a recovery mode option. Try that, and that should let you drop into the terminal without X.